# Creating custom CMS component controller for Hybris 2211

Tags: content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

We've created a new custom BannerComponent called CustomBannerComponent. This will hold a bannerText attribute. This will be used in our front end to change the text on our banners. The problem is that we need different images and text depending on the locale. For example, if we are in the English language, we get something that fits the expectations of the business (text is in English and image fits the market). What we want now is to create a custom CMS controller to control the bannerText and the media depending on the session's locale. I'm trying to create one extending AbstractCMSComponentController but found out that acceleratorstorefrontcommons is already deprecated. I've tried searching but everything I found in Google is old. Does Hybris have new documentation on how to control the content of CMS? A reference or simple step will do.

Comment: The text attribute that you're managing on your custom component should be localized -> in this way, you won't have to worry about component controllers handling the content based on the session's locale, because it's an OOTB behavior that is already handled (you can create a localized media attribute as well)